# Is it possible to “net user /active:yes” remotely?

Tags: windows

I have two computers, compA and compB

I have admin access to both. I also have remote access to both. However, im wondering. Is there an easier way to activate a local account on a remote machine? If I log into computer A can I remotely enable an account that resides locally on computer B?

Instead of having to remote into B to enable the account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both computers are on the same network, then
once you are logged into A, you may execute the `net use` command on B by using the
[psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
utility:

```
psexec \\compB net user user-name /active:yes
```

If necessary, you may also specify user and password on the command.